# Node version will not update using n

Tags: node.js, homebrew, yarnpkg, n

To give some context, I set up my machine using this Medium post, [Don’t Use `sudo` with `npm` …still](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92).

I installed Node using `brew` about a year and a half ago, which installed v12.18.1. I also installed `n` at the time using `brew`, but never had to change versions until now.

My `.zshrc` file includes the following:

```
# For globally installed npm packages (without using sudo)
export PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"

# Path to n (managing node versions)
export N_PREFIX="$HOME/.n"
export PATH="$PATH:$N_PREFIX/bin"
```

When I install Node v14 with `n`, the following occurs:

```
➜  ~ node -v
v12.18.1
➜  ~ n 14
   installed : v14.15.4 to /Users/myusername/.n/bin/node
      active : v12.18.1 at /usr/local/bin/node
➜  ~ node -v
v12.18.1
```

I see that the version was successfully installed; however, the active version doesn't update. I noticed that the path of the installed version is clearly different than the active version (reference  terminal output above), which I suspect is the issue.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.**

---

***Additional information:*** When I installed Node initially, `yarn` was not available despite the article linked at top stating it should be so I installed `n` using `brew`. To troubleshoot, I ran `brew uninstall n`, however, the following was output:

```
Warning: The following may be n configuration files and have not been removed!
If desired, remove them manually with `rm -rf`:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
```

And so then I ran `rm -rf /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d`. Nothing printed to the terminal after.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is you have `node` installed to two locations, and the one being installed by `n` is later in the `PATH` variable.

For interest, you can run `n doctor` and it should pick up this problem.

You could either uninstall the copy of node installed to `/usr/local/bin/node`, or rearrange your `PATH`. Instead of:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$N_PREFIX/bin"
```

try:

```
export PATH="$N_PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Hit the nail on the head. Thank you so much, @shadowspawn!

Running `n doctor` showed: `Checking n install destination priority in PATH... There is a version of node installed which will be found in PATH before the n installed version.`

By implementing the change suggested and re-sourcing the `.zshrc` file, everything seems to be working beautifully!