# switching node versions using n

Tags: node.js, pm2, n

```
    [root@xx.xx.xx.xx xxxx]# n
   installed : v14.8.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v10.21.0 at /bin/node
```

Installed node version 14.8.0 using n. Not sure how 10.21.0 was installed. Cannot delete or switch versions. I am using pm2 process manager and need the versions switched i.e dont want to run `n run v14.8.0 server.js` i would rather change the active version globally, so that running pm2 start would not need to specify a specific version. Please help.

Comment: You have two versions of node installed, and could either delete the old one, or modify your path. Try "n doctor" for clues, and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657802/node-version-will-not-update-using-n/65658906

Answer (score 0):

First, you can explicitly select /usr/local/bin/node by creating a file like

```sh
/usr/local/bin/node server.js
```

Make sure to rename it to something ending with `.sh`
Then to run it with pm2 you can do `pm2 run yourfilename.sh`

Second, you can use a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in server.js, so the first line must be

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
```

And you can run your script the way you were doing it before