# n failed to install/switch node in Linux?

Tags: node.js, n

I am trying to install/ switch node version in fly using [n](https://github.com/tj/n) since different build requires different version of node. n is able to download specified version but it is unable to installed to /usr/bin/node and still old version there.

```
05-Apr-2021 11:46:27       installed : v10.16.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
05-Apr-2021 11:46:27          active : v8.16.1 at /bin/node
```

when I run node --version command it returns the old version 8.16.1
apparently, n installed node to different location. is there a way to fix that? thank you in advance

Comment: You have two versions of node installed, and could either delete the old one, or modify your path. Try "n doctor" for clues, and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657802/node-version-will-not-update-using-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## N does not install to `/bin`, so the binary's location changed.

### tl;dr:

Reset `$PATH`: `PATH="$PATH"`

### What?

On a *NIX system, there are many binary locations: `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, or even `/home/USER/.local/bin` if configured.

### Why?

All the binary folders make it easier to organize.

### Why did `n` change the location?

To keep with standards, of course. `/usr[/local]/bin` is the traditional spot for package-installed binaries.

### Why didn't my shell see the new binary?

Shells use a "hash table" so they don't need to look through the `$PATH` again and again- wait, what's `$PATH`?

#### What's `PATH`?

PATH is a `:`-separated list of locations to find binaries to execute. For example, mine looks like this: `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/home/badboyhalocat/node_installs/bin:/home/badboyhalocat/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/home/badboyhalocat/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

The shell uses this to look up where to find the code to run.

### Fixing this

Just reset your PATH: `PATH="$PATH"`

Comment: thanks @logan it was issue with some symbolic link. n was install to /usr/local/bin but bamboo was looking at /usr/bin . link both solve problem